# python django 'str' object has no attribute 'delete'

Tags: python, django

i have a object:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=3)
user.first_name.delete()
user.save()
```

I want to delete the first name of the user and keep it blank. When I do so it says `'str' object has no attribute 'delete'`

Whats wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings don't have delete methods. Only models do. `user.first_name` is a string on the model, it's not a model itself. It simply doesn't make sense to want to "delete" a field value.

Instead you should set it to an empty string:

```
user.first_name = ''
```

Answer (score 4):

`user.first_name` refers to a string field in a database and yes, it does not have a `delete()` method in it. You can try setting it to `None`, like

```
user.first_name = None
```

or setting it to a blank string, like

```
user.first_name = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

**`delete()` method is defined for Model objects and not Model Fields.**

You are trying to apply `delete()` method on `first_name` which is a string(`CharField`).

If you intend to `'delete'` the `first_name` string, you can either set it to  `None` or an empty string `''`.

```
user = User.objects.get(id=3)
user.first_name = '' # set first_name to an empty string

# can also set first_name to None
# user.first_name = None 

user.save()
```